# CTCarrier carrierName list

Tags: ios, carrier

Is there a list of all carriers appearing in CTCarrier carrierName somewhere?
I'll need the exact strings.

Oh I'm looking for the AU (KDDI, Japan) carrier specifically.

Comment: Didn't find a list, however KDDI is just "KDDI".

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [list of mobile network codes and their corresponding carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code) useful. I'm pretty sure that if there to be a carrierName, there has to be a mobileNetworkCode.

Comment: carrierName seems to be a lot more consistent versus mobileNetworkCode. mobileNetworkCode disappears as soon as you remove the sim card, go in airplane mode, or similar as stated in Apple's docs. carrierName just sticks there. So I'll only be using carrierName, I thought. Anyway the Wikipedia list is not helpful when it comes to carrierName because Softbank in Japan renders "ソフトバンクモバイル" as carrierName on my device. And ソフトバンクモバイル is not appearing at all on Wikipedia.

Comment: *edit* Found ソフトバンクモバイル on the Japanese version of the article. Will have to find someone with a AU device still to make sure of the exact string.